# How many strings of English letters of length 8 contain at least 6 vowels?

Tags: combinatorics

I am having a hard time coming up with a way to calculate this.

There are 5 vowels so I think the number of strings that contain exactly 1 vowel would be:

## $5$ × $8$ × $21^5$

But I am not sure where to go from here. I believe I need to find a number to subtract from this number.

Comment: How many contain exactly $6$?  How many contain exactly $7$?  How many contain $8$?

Comment: Note:  trusting that you are counting "y" as a consonant, the computation you give for exactly one vowel is close but not correct.  In that situation there are $7$ consonant slots so you should have a factor of  $21^7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are

- $\binom825^621^2$ admissible strings with $6$ vowels ($\binom82$ ways to locate the consonants, then $5^6$ choices for the vowels and $21^2$ choices for the consonants)
- $\binom815^721^1$ admissible strings with $7$ vowels
- $\binom805^821^0$ admissible strings with $8$ vowels

Thus there are $206453125$ admissible strings in total.

Comment: Thank you! I think combinatorics finally clicked for me!